# Windows Servers Very Slow, Low CPU Usage Low Memory Usage

Tags: windows, performance

Apologies in advanced for the obscure question...
We have several servers in our infrastructure that have been behaving strangely lately. For example, a machine will become totally unresponsive, we wont be able to remote in apps running stop responding etc. We often have to reboot them during production when this happens.

When we look at performance counters we see less than 50% cpu utilization and less than 50% memory utilized. I'll use one machine as an example, it has 24 Cores (intel) and 32 GB of RAM. Disk is Raid 10 400GB 10k SAS (4 disks).

IO looks fine, network looks fine, etc. None of the counters I look at indicate any problems. Disk queue length never even hits 1.

Even when the machine is responsive when I try to launch an app (mmc.exe for example) it takes 5 minutes to show up.

The machine(s) are all running Server2012R2 with the latest patches. We are running Kaspersky Enterprise, but have been able to duplicate this behavior with it disabled/uninstalled/and fully running.

For example, I'll try to open MMC, Chrome and Powershell back to back to back. The server will do nothing for a couple minutes. Then all of a sudden all 3 apps open virtually at the same time.

I'm at a total loss right now. I dont know what to look at to identify whats going on with these servers.

Comment: Check in perfmon please for the disk IO too. Come back with the find data.

Comment: Disk Queue Length runs pretty much 0 constantly, we never even see it hit 1. We do notice that process Queue Length Gets pretty high, but I cant identify why.

Comment: For example, I'll try to open MMC, Chrome and Powershell back to back to back. The server will do nothing for a couple minutes. Then all of a sudden all 3 apps open virtually at the same time.

Comment: Run the System Performance data collector in perfmon until the problem occurs, then stop the data collector after you think it's collected sufficient data after the problem has occurred and view the automatically generated report. The report will highlight any resource issues that may be contributing to the problem.

Comment: And connect locally. Then with a little transportable switch. I have seen similar behavior based on you THINKING it is slow - when it was a very bad switch in between. Far shot, but you already ruled out the normal answers.

Comment: @TomTom we see the same behavior logged in locally. The other thing. Is windows Explorer always opens quickly, start menu responds instantly, but we do see process queues growing quickly when we try to launch apps.

Comment: Are these VMs running off of some storage like a SAN? Have someone check the physical disk or hosts perhaps? I've been burned by this so many times and often it's under the covers.

Comment: No these are are all dells

Comment: have same issue for around two month :| no utilization, but very low performance, some time remote desktop start with blank screen for several minutes

Comment: Same here. Did you guys find any solution for this?